# Прямая инициализация классов

Tags: c++

Почему следующая программа вместо `hello` и `0/1` выдаёт `1`?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
 
class Drob
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;
 
public:
    Drob(int numerator=0, int denominator=1) :
        m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator)
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
        assert(denominator != 0);
    }
 
    Drob(const Drob &drob) :
        m_numerator(drob.m_numerator), m_denominator(drob.m_denominator)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor worked here!\n"; 
    }
 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Drob &d1);
};
 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Drob &d1)
{
    out << d1.m_numerator << "/" << d1.m_denominator;
    return out;
}
 
int main()
{
    Drob sixSeven (Drob());
    std::cout << sixSeven << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если заменить `Drob sixSeven (Drob());` на `Drob sixSeven {Drob()};` или на `Drob sixSeven = Drob();` то результатом будет `hello` и `0/1`, а вот в случае с прямой инициализацией результат другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно most vexing parse `Drob sixSeven (Drob());` является объявлением функции `sixSeven` и `operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Drob &d1)` даже не вызывается.

Прямая инициализация - это `Drob sixSeven{};`

Comment: посмотрел предупреждение : `warning: the address of 'Drob sixSeven(Drob (*)())' will never be NULL` Это значит функция `sixSeven` с аргументом функции `Drob (*)()` ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Да, `Drob()` в скобках парсится как указатель на функцию с сигнатурой (void) -> Drob.

Comment: `Drob sixSeven{};` - это value-инициализация. Я так понял, "прямая" - это когда >0 аргументов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я обычно под прямой подразумеваю direct, т.е. когда без = или доп. кастов. Ну а тут это еще в смысле "правильная", так как нечего Drob по два раза писать.

Comment: Я понял что речь про direct, и похоже это не она. А то, что правильная, это да.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вот в стандарте такой вариант обзывают direct `Z b{};                          // OK: direct initialization syntax used` http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#example-2

Comment: Хмм, странно это. А http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#15.1 говорит, что это вообще list-initialization (которая в свою очередь делает value-initialization).